# Timing Functions: Double Returning 0 MS

Tags: c++, double

I am writing an in-depth test program for a data structure I had to write for a class. I am trying to time how long it takes functions to execute and store them in an array for later printing. To double check that it was working I decided to print it immediately, and I found out it is not working.

Here is the code where I get the times and store them in an array that is in a struct.

```
void test1(ArrayLinkedBag<ItemType> &bag,TestAnalytics &analytics){
    clock_t totalStart;
  clock_t incrementalStart;
  clock_t stop; //Both timers stop at the same time;
  // Start TEST 1
  totalStart = clock();
  bag.debugPrint();

  cout << "Bag Should Be Empty, Checking..." << endl;
  incrementalStart = clock();
  checkEmpty<ItemType>(bag);
  stop = clock();
  analytics.test1Times[0] = analytics.addTimes(incrementalStart,stop);
  analytics.test1Times[1] = analytics.addTimes(totalStart,stop);
  cout << analytics.test1Times[0] << setprecision(5) << "ms" << endl;
  std::cout << "Time: "<< setprecision(5)  << (stop - totalStart) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;
    cout << "===========================================" << endl; //So I can find the line easier

}
```

Here is the code where I am doing the calculation that I am putting in the array, this function is located in a TestAnalytics struct

```
double addTimes(double start, double stop){
    return (stop - start)/ (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
  }
```

Here is a snippet of the output I am getting:

```
Current Head: -1
Current Size: 0
Cell: 1, Index: 0, Item: 6317568, Next Index: -2
Cell: 2, Index: 1, Item: 4098, Next Index: -2
Cell: 3, Index: 2, Item: 6317544, Next Index: -2
Cell: 4, Index: 3, Item: -683175280, Next Index: -2
Cell: 5, Index: 4, Item: 4201274, Next Index: -2
Cell: 6, Index: 5, Item: 6317536, Next Index: -2
Bag Should Be Empty, Checking...
The Bag Is Empty
0ms
Time: 0 ms
===========================================
```

I am trying to calculate the time as per a different post on this site.
I am using clang compiler on an UNIX system. Is it possible that the number is still too small to show above 0?

Comment: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000` might be integer division; not sure if that is related to your problem

Comment: @M.M I am casting that to a double though. I have just noticed that my stop and totalStart both printing 0.

Comment: change to `1000.0`  , there's no point casting to a double after you already did integer division

Comment: Just gave it a shot, no luck

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're stuck with an old (pre-C++ 11) compiler/library, I'd use the functions from the `<chrono>` header:

```
template <class ItemType>
void test1(ArrayLinkedBag<ItemType> &bag){
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    bag.debugPrint();
    auto first = high_resolution_clock::now();
    checkEmpty(bag);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << " first time: " << duration_cast<microseconds>(first - start).count() << " us\n";
    std::cout << "second time: " << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << " us\n";
}
```

Some parts are a bit verbose (to put it nicely) but it still works reasonably well. `duration_cast` supports difference types down to (at least) `nanoseconds`, which is typically sufficient for timing even relatively small/fast pieces of code (though it's not guaranteed that it uses a timer with nanosecond precision).

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on trying this tomorrow when I get back up, I'll let you know though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jerry's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46598145/576911) (which I've upvoted), I wanted to add just a little more information that might be helpful.

For timing I recommend `steady_clock` over `high_resolution_clock` because `steady_clock` is guaranteed to not be adjusted (especially backwards) during your timing.  Now on Visual Studio and clang, this can't possibly happen because `high_resolution_clock` and `steady_clock` are exactly the same type.  However if you're using gcc, `high_resolution_clock` is the same type as `system_clock`, which is subject to being adjusted at any time (say by an NTP correction).

But if you use `steady_clock`, then on every platform you have a stop-watch-like timer:  Not good for telling you the time of day, but not subject to being corrected at an inopportune moment.

Also, if you use [my free, open-source, header-only `<chrono>` extension library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#duration_io), it can stream out durations in a much more friendly manner, without having to use `duration_cast` nor `.count()`.  It will print out the duration units right along with the value.

Finally, if you call `steady_clock::now()` multiple times in a row (with nothing in between), and print out that difference, then you can get a feel for how precisely your implementation is able to time things. Can it time something as short as femtoseconds? Probably not.  Is it as coarse as milliseconds?  We hope not.

Putting this all together, the following program was compiled like this:

```
clang++ test.cpp -std=c++14 -O3 -I../date/include
```

The program:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using date::operator<<;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        auto t0 = steady_clock::now();
        auto t1 = steady_clock::now();
        auto t2 = steady_clock::now();
        auto t3 = steady_clock::now();
        auto t4 = steady_clock::now();
        auto t5 = steady_clock::now();
        auto t6 = steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << t1-t0 << '\n';
        std::cout << t2-t1 << '\n';
        std::cout << t3-t2 << '\n';
        std::cout << t4-t3 << '\n';
        std::cout << t5-t4 << '\n';
        std::cout << t6-t5 << '\n';
    }
}
```

And output for me on macOS:

```
150ns
80ns
69ns
53ns
63ns
64ns
88ns
54ns
66ns
66ns
59ns
56ns
59ns
69ns
76ns
74ns
73ns
73ns
64ns
60ns
58ns
...
```